# External CSS won't load in IOS6 Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, ios6

I have a simple webpage that calls up to external stylesheets, one for google's webfonts, the other to a css file on my own server.

This works fine for desktop tests on IE9, FF, Chrome as well as Android chrome and IOS6 Safari -

but on IOS6 - Chrome no luck.

On chrome even though the webfont stylesheet sheet loads, my own external stylesheet doesn't - does anyone have a clue?

The webpage [my webpage](http://plumplucker.com/animated/MotherOfAllFiction.html)
My stylesheet [my stylesheet](http://plumplucker.com/animated/angrywords.css)

Comment: Just a little note, your page looks very much like Google's malicious warning page. Scared me at first.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that. I will change the design of the that starting notice.

Comment: Next step, ensure that it validates. Right now you've got an encoding problem: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fplumplucker.com%2Fanimated%2FMotherOfAllFiction.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Now it validates, validator doesn't like `<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">`

Comment: Guessing it didn't fix the problem though?

Comment: No, Christain. I have also tried removing the google webfont to no avail. I am due to publish tomorrow so I guess I will move the css inline tonight. But thanks for your concern. Weird problem!

Comment: ... and then out of the blue the problem went away without my realizing what I had changed. Now it works and so it goes